# Validation constraints not working on my Symfony3 project

Tags: validation, symfony

I couldn't make my validation constraints **$form->isValid()** works.
The book name is always valid even if I put a name with length less than 10...

On my AppBundle\Resources\config\validation\book.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Book:
properties:
    bookName:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 10
```

neither from the formBuilder

```
$builder->add('bookName', TextType::class, array(
            'constraints' => new Length(array('min' => 10))))
```

Here is my framework.validation config

```
framework:
    validation: ~
```

and the default config is

```
framework:
    validation:
        enabled: true
        enable_annotations: false
```

Need help please.

Thanks

Comment: you should provide a example of how you are using the form, i.e where the isValid() call is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It was because I used a [Form Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes) and I set a [validation_groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups) like below:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('creation'),
        'data_class'        => 'AppBundle\Entity\Book',
    ));
}
```

And I didn't specified it on the formBuilder options.

```
$form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

---

**Solution 1**: is to remove the definition of the validation groups from the Form class default option.

**Solution 2**: is to add the validation group for the validation:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($book, array(
    'validation_groups' => array('creation'),
))->add(...);
```